# Python multiple processes, inter-process communication, architecture

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I started doing a simple command line chat, then I learned about tkinter and added GUI, then I added voice support.

As soon as I learned that python threads suck, I started using Processes and pipes for inter-process communication.

The main process, launches 3 processes to deal with: GUI, sound input, sound output.

The main process connects to the server, sends/receives messages (updating the GUI).
The GUI process runs the tkinter loop and communicates with the main process when needed.

The way I call procedures in another process is by sending, through a pipe, the name of the method and arguments for it, which the receiving process will execute. There is no return, only calls.

I would like know the wrongs of this architecture and alternatives.
What design patterns exist for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html) module? It makes calling functions in a subprocess look as much like calling a function in a background thread as possible.

Comment: I use that module to create Process and Pipe. What do u mean by calling functions in a subprocess?